# Не отображается картинка категории Python Django

Tags: python, django

Почему не отображается картинка категории. Сайт про разные софты и в каждом нужно выводить фото категории и саму категорию. Категория выводиться, но фото нет.

Вот models.py(использовал FileField, потому что фото категорий в формате .svg):

```
class Category(models.Model):
    img = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Фото категории')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Название')
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        ordering = ['name']
```

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    softs = Soft.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.filter(parent_category=None)
    context = {'softs': softs, 'categories': categories}
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', context)
```

И сам index.html:

**soft.category.img.url выдает ошибку "The 'img' attribute has no file associated with it.", а soft.category.img понятное дело не работает.**

```
{% for soft in softs %}
<article class="soft">
    <div class="poster"><img src="{{ soft.img.url }}"></div>
    <div class="details">
        <h1><a href="#0">{{ soft.title }}</a></h1>
        <div class="meta">
            <span class="pubdate">{{ soft.published|date:"d.m.Y" }}</span>
            
            <span class="cat icon"><a href="#0" class="cat"><img src="{{ soft.category.img }}" width="16px"> {{ soft.category.name }}</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
{% endfor %}
```

**Всем откликнувшимся заранее спасибо.**

Comment: Ну так а картинка-то у категории вообще есть? Текст ошибки говорит, что картинки нет.

Comment: Конечно есть, кроме софта есть еще и меню с категориями, и там эти картинки отображаются.

Comment: А я вам не верю, покажите скриншот всех категорий из админки или print(repr(soft.category.img.name)) например

Comment: да, конечно. https://ibb.co/HGmWc2b и https://ibb.co/NrbZ5Pc

Comment: могу еще с сайта скрин скинуть)

Comment: Вы показали одну категорию, а что насчёт остальных девяти? Ну и насчёт «и там эти картинки отображаются» — какой «там» шаблон вывода картинок и чем он отличается от проблемного шаблона? Ведь не бывает так, что одна и та же картинка в одном месте работает, а в другом нет, значит где-то должно быть какое-то отличие

Comment: Да, конечно же отличие есть, сейчас все напишу отдельным ответом, тут не очень удобно

Comment: Ответы предназначены для исчерпывающих решений, а для дополнения вопроса используйте кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1150042/edit)

Comment: Хорошо, тогда вот: https://pastebin.com/UVHuCfFG

Comment: В меню вы, видимо, не выводите картинки подкатегорий, а soft.category это возможно как раз подкатегория с отсутствующей картинкой, проверьте админку ещё раз

Comment: Нет, картинки для подкатегорий не нужны, мне нужно вывести картинку категории, к которой относиться данная подкатегория. Название подкатегории я вывожу, картинка не получается.

Comment: А, ну если вам нужна картинка родительской категории, то конечно же нужно писать `{{ soft.category.parent_category.img.url }}`, иначе вы пытаетесь выводить картинку подкатегории которая конечно же не существует

Comment: Да, сработало! Спасибо большое. Целый день мучился, просто еще новичок в этом)

Answer (score 2):

Возможно все таки, что у одной из категории отсутствует img.
Попробуйте сделать проверку:

```
    <span class="cat icon"><a href="#0" class="cat"><img src="{% if soft.category.img %}{{ soft.category.img }} {% endif %}" width="16px"> {{ soft.category.name }}</a></span>
```

UPD: Возможно не практично, но попробуйте такую проверку:

```
{% if soft.category.img and soft.category.parent_category == None %}{{ soft.category.img }} {% endif %}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. У меня есть категория и подкатегории, относящиеся к данной категории. картинок для подкатегорий нет, только для категорий.

Comment: Спасибо, но ответ уже получил в комментариях)